# 3-Step Transformation to Humulone

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, nucleophilic-substitution, electrophilic-substitution, rearrangements

[image]

I have some ideas on how this transformation may occur. We're currently studying Ch. 3 (Polar Rxn's under Acidic Conditions) from Grossman's book.

I've found some data online that shows we can perform a standard Friedal-Crafts acylation using -ClCOCH2CH(CH3)2 and AlCl3 to add the substituted ketone alkyl chain.

The next steps I can think of are prenylation using BrCH2CHCH(CH3)2 to add to both of the remaining unsubstituted benzene positions. I've seen data using this bromo-prenyl compound and KOH but our chapter is on reactions under acidic conditions so I don't know if this will fit the theme.

Alternatively, could we begin by nitration with conversion to an alcohol group, making 1,3,4,5-tetrahydroxybenzene, then acylate, and then perform 2 successive alkylations with ferric bromide to add both prenyl groups?

This has been challenging for me to get done in 3 steps. Our last few lectures covered the Prins, Sakurai, Bischler-Napieralski, Vilsmeir-Haack, and just general rearrangement, SN1, SN2, E1, and E2 reactions.

Comment: When you include a reference, please make it a proper citation. Could you expand how that is involved with beer, please.

Comment: Hey Martin, I have a link to a patent that I've found that involves some of this work: https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/f4/ef/3b/36b82a35dd04a8/US9340479.pdf I also found a paper on this using 1,3,4,5-tetrahydroxybenzene though: https://www.journal.csj.jp/doi/epdf/10.1246/bcsj.62.3034

Comment: The chemistry on my assignment has to do with compounds found in beer, mainly alpha-hops (humulone) and iso-alpha-hops (iso-humulones). I ultimately need to show an acid catalyzed rearrangement from humulone to the 5-membered iso-humulone molecule but I feel comfortable doing that part so I didn't include it. The alpha-hops convert to the iso-alpha-hops during the "boil process" when beer is produced.

Comment: Here is a link to a 2 step transformation relating to the second paper in my original comment: https://tinyurl.com/2fkhfw5m

Comment: @PhDeezNutz OP is probably referring to that reaction. However, it involves a base (NaH) and OP wants to get around that and use acid solely I believe.

Comment: I have an idea for a 4-step mechanism but I can't get down to 3. I've seen DMP oxidize phenols into adjacent ketones on an aromatic system, and maybe it can do the same here. Then you can do grignard. All before that, you would have done Freidal's Craft selectively for the carbons not connected to an oxygen.

Comment: How do we know that three steps are possible?  Is the goal to find a synthetic pathway, or to describe the biosynthesis of humulone?  I'm very unclear what you are actually asking for in this question.